# lack of authorisations in process to obtain a refresh token?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to generate a refresh token in order to authenticate an external sharepoint add-in.
I followed the documentaion here : https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-data-integration-connectors/h2l/preparing-to-use-microsoft-sharepoint-online-connector/preparing-to-use-microsoft-sharepoint-online-connector/step-4--generate-the-authorization-code.html
I'm stuck in this step. I have the screen where I can click the "trust it" button, but instead of having an error screen with the code in the url, I have the error : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and no code in the url but **?error=server_error&error_description=The%20remote%20server%20returned%20an%20error%3A%20%28401%29%20Unauthorized%2E**

Answer (score 0):

I follow step by step the procedure below, no problem :

https://spshell.blogspot.com/2015/03/sharepoint-online-o365-oauth.html

In the very first step you must enter a redirect_uri, I've entered 'default.aspx' at the end. You just need to specify 'https://localhost/' and nothing else.